# TypeScript shorten generic function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, typescript-generics

I am using `Sequelize 6.6.5` with `TypeScript 4.4.3` on Node `14.17.6`

`db/models/User.ts` (only relevant parts)

```js
import {
  Sequelize,
  Model,
  DataTypes,
  Optional,
  ModelAttributeColumnOptions,
} from 'sequelize';

import { FlagPositions, Flags } from '../types';

export interface IUserFlags {
  isDev: boolean;
  isAdmin: boolean;
  isMod: boolean;
}

export const flagPositions: FlagPositions<IUserFlags> = {
  isDev: 0,
  isAdmin: 1,
  isMod: 2,
};

export interface IUserAttributes extends Flags, IUserFlags {
  id: number;

  name: string;

  email: string;

  // ...
}

export interface IUserCreationAttributes
  extends Optional<
    IUserAttributes,
    | 'id'
    | 'flags'
    | 'isDev'
    | 'isAdmin'
    | 'isMod'
  > {}

export class User
  extends Model<IUserAttributes, IUserCreationAttributes>
  implements IUserAttributes
{
  public id!: number;

  public name!: string;

  public email!: string;

  public flags!: number;

  public isDev!: boolean;
  public isAdmin!: boolean;
  public isMod!: boolean;

  // ...
}

export function init(sequelize: Sequelize): void {
  User.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      // ...
      flags: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0,
      },
      isDev: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        get(): boolean {
          return !!((this.flags >> flagPositions.isDev) & 1);
        },
        set(value: boolean): void {
          const flags = this.getDataValue('flags');

          const mask = 1 << flagPositions.isDev;

          this.setDataValue('flags', value ? flags | mask : flags & ~mask);
        },
      },
      isAdmin: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        get(): boolean {
          return !!((this.flags >> flagPositions.isAdmin) & 1);
        },
        set(value: boolean): void {
          const flags = this.getDataValue('flags');

          const mask = 1 << flagPositions.isAdmin;

          this.setDataValue('flags', value ? flags | mask : flags & ~mask);
        },
      },
      isMod: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        get(): boolean {
          return !!((this.flags >> flagPositions.isMod) & 1);
        },
        set(value: boolean): void {
          const flags = this.getDataValue('flags');

          const mask = 1 << flagPositions.isMod;

          this.setDataValue('flags', value ? flags | mask : flags & ~mask);
        },
      },
    },
    { sequelize, tableName: 'users' },
  );
}
```

`../types`

```js
interface Flags {
  flags: number;
}

type FlagPositions<F extends Record<keyof F, boolean>> = {
  [K in keyof F]: number;
};
```

As you can see, the code for the flag virtuals is basically duplicated (WET).

I wanted to have something like this

```js
isDev: createFlagVirtual<IUserFlags>(flagPositions, 'isDev');
```

After a long list of errors, I came up with

```js
function createFlagVirtual<
  TModelAttributes extends Flags,
  TModelCreationAttributes extends Partial<TModelAttributes>,
  TModel extends Model<TModelAttributes, TModelCreationAttributes> &
    TModelAttributes,
  TFlags extends Record<keyof TFlags, boolean>,
  TFlag extends keyof TFlags = keyof TFlags,
>(
  positions: FlagPositions<TFlags>,
  flag: TFlag,
): ModelAttributeColumnOptions<TModel> {
  return {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get(): boolean {
      return !!((this.flags >> positions[flag]) & 1);
    },
    set(value: boolean): void {
      const flags = this.getDataValue('flags');

      const mask = 1 << positions[flag];

      this.setDataValue('flags', value ? flags | mask : flags & ~mask);
    },
  };
}
```

Wondering how I call it?:

```js
createFlagVirtual<IUserAttributes, IUserCreationAttributes, User, IUserFlags>(
  flagPositions,
  'isMod',
);
```

Yah; not so DRY.

On top of which, typescript still has no idea that `'flags'` can be passed to `this.getDataValue`, atleast according to vscode intellisense. However, it knows that directly accessing `this.flags` is a `number`.

I want to know how to shorten the call to `createFlagVirtual` so that the following works `createFlagVirtual<IUserFlags>(flagPositions, 'isDev');`. TypeScript should know what can be passed to the second argument, aka a `keyof` `IUserFlags`. Also, in the implementation, `this.getDataValue` should know that `'flags'` is a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself

```js
function createFlagVirtual<
  TFlags extends Record<keyof TFlags, boolean>,
  TModel extends Model<Flags, {}> & Flags = Model<Flags, {}> & Flags,
>(
  positions: FlagPositions<TFlags>,
  name: keyof TFlags,
): ModelAttributeColumnOptions<TModel> {
  return {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get(): boolean {
      return !!((this.getDataValue('flags') >> positions[name]) & 1);
    },
    set(value: boolean): void {
      const flags = this.getDataValue('flags');

      const mask = 1 << positions[name];

      this.setDataValue('flags', value ? flags | mask : flags & ~mask);
    },
  };
}
```

Used as

```js
createFlagVirtual<IUserFlags>(flagPositions, 'isDev')
// or
createFlagVirtual<IUserFlags, User>(flagPositions, 'isDev'),
```

The key part was `TModel extends Model<Flags, {}> & Flags = Model<Flags, {}> & Flags`.

`Model<Flags, {}>` is what allows `this.getDataValue` to know that `'flags'` is an allowed value and `& Flags` lets typescript know that a direct `this.flags` access is a `number`.

EDIT: This shows what a mess TypeScript can be and how it can actually slow down development by making the programmer focus on something that doesn't matter in the end. I have moved my codebase to vanilla javascript once again.